# How to fix "maximum number of clients reached"?

Tags: xorg

About 30 Oct I ran recent updates for 12.04 64bit. No errors occurred.

Next day when I booted computer most apps would not start or if started (eg Chrome) other app windows do not appear. Trying a command line start on most apps gives this message: "Maximum number of clients reachedError: cannot open display: :0" The 'error' part of message not always the same.

Have tried to find solution on Ubuntu forums and other Linux web sites, but cannot find a solution. HELP please.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you install Lastpass extension for Google Chrome browser. Try to remove it!